# Unable to load a webpage using TOMCAT 9.0, Java, Hibernate, Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to load a webpage: http://localhost:8080/oilgasweb/

Its giving the below error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
> Type Status Report
> Message /oilgasweb/
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66574053/edit) your question and add some details, like your `server.xml` configuration, the servers startup logs (`catalina.<date>.log`) to see if your application is being deployed. If it is, the problem might be in your deployment descriptor (application's `web.xml`) or `@WebServlet` annotations.

Comment: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [gov.utah.ogm.oilgas.web.common.listeners.HibernateEMFactoryListener]
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No name provided and multiple persistence units found

Comment: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [gov.utah.ogm.oilgas.web.common.listeners.HibernateSessionFactoryListener]
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [gov.utah.ogm.oilgas.web.common.listeners.HibernateSessionFactoryListener]
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [gov.utah.ogm.oilgas.web.common.listeners.HibernateEMFactoryListener]
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66574053/edit), instead of adding comments. If those are [`ServletContextListener`s](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), that's the reason why your application didn't start.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I resolved it. One of the files was corrupt and I changed it and it worked.